# How can one set a background image in a Django Template?

Tags: html, css, django-templates

How can one set a background image in a Django Template? Let's say the url of my background image is at www.randomlink.com/static/backgroundimagesplash.jpg

I took a look at the [Pinterest](https://pinterest.com/) homepage. As many of you know, Pinterest was built using Django. I inspected a few of their elements on their home page.

One of the graphics they used was this splash image here: [PinterestSplashImage.jpg](https://s-passets-ec.pinimg.com/webapp/app/desktop/images/logged_out_splash.77aa6339.jpg?1373235165)

The splash image is set at the bottom center. One thing I noticed is that the splash image resizes relative to the resizing of the browser that it is viewed in.

This is my current home page template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<link href="www.randomlink.com/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
body{
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    {{ state }}
    <form action="/login/" method="post">
        {% if next %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        {% endif %}
        username:
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
        password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can one set the www.randomlink.com/static/backgroundimagesplash.jpg at the bottom centre and make it re sizable just like Pinterest did with their home page? (For the sake of argument, the splash image will be the same dimensions as the Pinterest splash image)

Comment: Django templates are HTML. So you should ask how to set a background in a HTML page. You can set a background-image to the html or body tag. Usually you set the main visual elements in the base.html file.

Answer (score 6):

Look how I did it: In the template I put the following line:

```
<body id="bg" style="background-image: url('{% static "images/33.jpg"%}')";>
```

And in the css:

```
#bg{
    background-size: 1800px 900px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

As a result I obtained a fixed background and with the proportions of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It question not relate to Django. It pure html with CSS.

To scale image while resize window you should use the property `background-size: contain` of the CSS3.

To place to the bottom and to center you can use the properties `position: absolute; background-position: 50% 100%;` of CSS.

Finally example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.splash {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url('https://s-passets-ec.pinimg.com/webapp/app/desktop/images/logged_out_splash.77aa6339.jpg?1373235165');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 461px;
    max-width: 1034px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="splash"></div>
```

see demo on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBq9y/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set backgroung image in your template:

```
 <div class="inner" style="background-image: url({% static "frontend/img/parallax-image.jpg" %}");>
```